# protobuf-net version -3.0.73 ,SaveContractsToZipStream method is breaking with error: System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

> ```
> Method not found: 'System.String ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.GetSchema(System.Type, ProtoBuf.Meta.ProtoSyntax)'.'
>  Stack Trace:
> System.MissingMethodException
>   HResult=0x80131513
>   Message=Method not found: 'System.String ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.GetSchema(System.Type, ProtoBuf.Meta.ProtoSyntax)'.
>   Source=Components.ProtoBuf.Generator
>   StackTrace:
>    at Components.ProtoBuf.Generator.ProtoDefinitionGenerator.GetProto3Definition(Type type, RuntimeTypeModel typeModel)
>    at Components.ProtoBuf.Generator.ProtoDefinitionGenerator.CreateProtoDefinition(Type type, IReadOnlyCollection`1 dependencies, RuntimeTypeModel typeModel)
>    at Components.ProtoBuf.Generator.SerializationUtility.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GenerateProtoDefinitionsOfUsedTypes>b__1(KeyValuePair`2 e)
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
>    at Components.ProtoBuf.Generator.SerializationUtility.GenerateProtoDefinitionsOfUsedTypes(IReadOnlyCollection`1 contractContainers, HashSet`1 excludedMethods, RuntimeTypeModel typeModel)
>    at Components.ProtoBuf.Generator.SerializationUtility.SaveContractsToZipStream(RuntimeTypeModel typeModel, IReadOnlyCollection`1 contractContainers, HashSet`1 excludedMethods)
>    at WebApi.Controllers.ContractsController.Get() in Controllers\ContractsController.cs:line 38
>    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> ```

Comment: You are serializing/deserializing.  Are you serializing or deserializing?  I think you are deserializing data genertated with one version of your app and then deserializing with a different version.  You cannot change the serialize object and expect to be able to be able to deserialize the data.

Comment: @jdweng the above stacktrace is nothing to do with serialization, and even if it was: it shouldn't (and hopefully doesn't!) fail in that way.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how to reproduce the exception?  Specifically, can you share an example of a type that causes the exception to be thrown?

Comment: This is very intriguing to me. I can't think of an obvious cause. Are you using the pruning linker, for example for a minimal standalone (no dotnet framework dependency) deployment? Also: what exact runtime is this, and how might I reproduce it minimally?

Comment: @MarcGravell : I do not agree!!!.  A Controller uses Xml deserialization and a schema which is what the error messages are indicating.

Comment: @jdwang I don't want to "be that guy", but: I wrote the library, and I understand the stack trace; it isn't serializing here

Comment: Hypothesis: are you perhaps using some intermediate library (yours or 3rd party) that is targeting protobuf-net v2.4? A very small number of things moved between TypeModel and RuntimeTypeModel during the v3 work - although in checking, it seems to be there: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Core/Meta/TypeModel.cs#L1778 - I'd be very interested in seeing some code here! And knowing what version of protobuf-net.dll actually appears in your build output folder.